# how to stop pdf's from being download in iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I am using google web viewer and I don't want user to download that file.
How can I stop it from being download in android mobile browser,I'm thinking of disabling right click,will it work?

Comment: There is no real way to prevent that. There are general reasons for that: if you want to display an object in an `iframe`, then you have to publish it for that purpose. A published object can be accessed by a client. And since you have no real control about what a client does you have to accept and respond to client requests. You can somehow try to make life harder for clients, force them to work around one or two hurdles you implemented, but there is no real way to achieve what you want. It all boils down to: _you cannot publish and withhold a document at the same time._

Comment: what if i disable right click in iframe,don't you think i would be able to save my doc from large number of users

Comment: As said: you can try to implement a few hurdles, but anyone with a minimal knowledge of how the web works will be able to download, share the document and, especially, _share the direct link to the document_.

Comment: What I don't understand here: if you publish that document, then it obviously is meant to be read. If so, then _why_ do you try to _prevent_ people from accessing it? Why are you interested in _how_ people access the data you publish? That makes little sense...

Comment: ok,i agree with you,what other hurdles i should use

Comment: None, as simple as that.